running keytool to get SHA1 certificate only loops me to the list
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore
this is the code im running in the cmd
but it only shows the list
Lists entries in a keystore

Options:

 -rfc                    output in RFC style
 -alias <alias>          alias name of the entry to process
 -keystore <keystore>    keystore name
 -cacerts                access the cacerts keystore
 -storepass <arg>        keystore password
 -storetype <type>       keystore type
 -providername <name>    provider name
 -addprovider <name>     add security provider by name (e.g. SunPKCS11)
   [-providerarg <arg>]    configure argument for -addprovider
 -providerclass <class>  add security provider by fully-qualified class name
   [-providerarg <arg>]    configure argument for -providerclass
 -providerpath <list>    provider classpath
 -v                      verbose output
 -protected              password through protected mechanism

is there a fix?
Im tryng to get a SHA1 from this link

It it possible that your %USERPROFILE% path contains a space? If yes you have to put the path in quotes: keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore"
